# How to remove duplicates in an array by using only one for loop?

Tags: ios, data-structures

```
NSArray *inputArray = @[11, 45, 54, 32, 11, 56, 45, 76, 23, 87, 54, 45];
NSArray *outputArray = @[11, 45, 54, 32, 56, 76, 23, 87];
```

How can I achieve this in Objective C without **sorting**, because sorting is using one `for` loop.

Comment: Hi, you need to provide more information i.e some code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You would have to use some kind of data structure to keep track of the elements you have already encountered as you iterate through the array.  Nobody will be able to give specific help until you give more information.

Comment: just edited question now, please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
NSArray *inputArray = @[11, 45, 54, 32, 11, 56, 45, 76, 23, 87, 54, 45];
NSArray *outputArray = [inputArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

If you care about ordering, you can create a new mutable array, loop through each object in the old array and only add it if it doesn't already exist:

```
NSMutableArray *uniqueItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id item in allItems)
if (![uniqueItems containsObject:item])
    [uniqueItems addObject:item];
```

If not, it's much simpler to just use a set:

```
NSSet *uniqueItems = [NSSet setWithArray:allItems];
```

Comment: i don't  want to use containsObject: method because this also will use one for loop internally.

Comment: I don't want to use NSSet. Is this possible to use only array.

Comment: @balaechat What's the issue with using a loop?

Comment: @Shruti Create a `NSMutableSet` and add items direct to the set, it will not add duplicate items.  Therefore, one for loop without `containsObject`. OFFTOPIC: I have a feeling that this is an interview question :))))

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray *inputArray = @[@11, @45, @54, @32, @11, @56, @45, @76, @23, @87, @54, @45];

    NSMutableSet *outputSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    NSMutableArray *outputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    for (NSNumber *num in inputArray)
    {
        [outputSet addObject:num];

        if (outputSet.count > outputArray.count)
        {
            [outputArray addObject:num];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can remove duplicates in this manner.
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (arr[abs(arr[i])] >= 0)
     arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])];
   else
     printf(" %d ", abs(arr[i]));
   }
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.